# Need to stop comma symbol for one occurance by using xslt

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I don't need the comma symbol in the last occurrence of item list elements using xslt

My input xml file is:

```
    <items>

    <item>
    <statement>I’m afraid</statement>
    <response>
    <p>Some complications</p>
    </response>
    <media>
    <type>html</type>
    <link>Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-1.avi</link>
    </media>
    </item>

    <item>
    <statement>I don’t know</statement>
    <response>
    <p>Some complications</p>
    </response>
    <media>
    <type>html</type>
    <link>Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-2.avi</link>
    </media>
    </item>

    <item>
    <statement>I don’t know</statement>
    <response>
    <p>Some complications</p>
    </response>
    <media>
    <type>html</type>
    <link>Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-3.avi</link>
    </media>
    </item>

    </items>
```

XSL i used as for json output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:json="http://json.org/" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[1]/media" />,
    items: [
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() &gt; 1]"/>
    ]
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    {
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    },
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="statement">
    "statement": "<xsl:apply-templates/>",
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="media">
    media: {
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    }
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="type">
    "type": "<xsl:apply-templates/>"
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:text>"link": "files/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '/')[last()]"/>"
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My json output which i got is:

```
items: [
{

"statement": "I’m afraid",

"response": "Some complications",

media: {

"type": "html"
"link": "files/Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-1.avi"

}

},

{

"statement": "I don’t know",

"response": "Some complications",

media: {

"type": "html"
"link": "files/Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-2.avi"

}

},

{

"statement": "I don’t know",

"response": "Some complications",

media: {

"type": "html"
"link": "files/Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-3.avi"

}

},
]
```

But i want to remove the comma at the last item (},) symbol as like below:

```
items: [
{

"statement": "I’m afraid",

"response": "Some complications",

media: {

"type": "html"
"link": "files/Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-1.avi"

}

},

{

"statement": "I don’t know",

"response": "Some complications",

media: {

"type": "html"
"link": "files/Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-2.avi"

}

},

{

"statement": "I don’t know",

"response": "Some complications",

media: {

"type": "html"
"link": "files/Brightcove.com%2FZ678766-3.avi"

}

}
]
```

Please help me on this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the item template from

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    {
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    },
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
    {
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    }
</xsl:template>
```

That is, output a comma before every item except the first.